# CMake fails to link a shared library decorated with a suffix (like somelib.so.1). Is there any way around?

Tags: c++, cmake, nvcc, amd-rocm, hip

I'm experimenting with `hip/ROCm` and I'm exploring the cross-platform capabilities.

While, I'm impressed with how welcoming is to port CUDA implementations on a AMD-gpu. I'm having a difficult time doing the opposite. More specifically, I'm failing to compile with `CMake` and `hipcc` (here a wrapper for the `nvcc` compiler) to build hip-applications on a NVidia-platform.

For example, I wrote a simple `Sgemm` [example](https://github.com/ROCm/hipBLAS/blob/develop/clients/samples/example_sgemm.cpp) using the respective `hipblas` library.
The following `cmakelists.txt` manages to compile my example it without much hassle on a AMD-platform:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(myPrototypes VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Define ROCM_PATH if not defined
if (NOT DEFINED ROCM_PATH)
  set(ROCM_PATH "/opt/rocm" CACHE STRING "Default ROCM installation directory.")
endif()

# Search for rocm in common locations
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${ROCM_PATH}/hip" "${ROCM_PATH}")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${ROCM_PATH}/hip/cmake")

# Find hip
find_package(HIP MODULE REQUIRED)
find_package(hipblas REQUIRED)

# Generate a compile_commands.json
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# Set compilation standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${HIP_HIPCC_EXECUTABLE})
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINKER   ${HIP_HIPCC_EXECUTABLE})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Library:
add_library(hip_sampleLib SHARED hip_sampleLib.hip.cpp hip_sampleLib.h)
target_link_libraries(hip_sampleLib PRIVATE roc::hipblas)

# Executables:
add_executable(test_sampleLib.run test_sampleLib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_sampleLib.run hip_sampleLib)
```

However, on a NVidia platform I get:

```bash
$ cmake ..
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: $HOME/Depots/devlibrary/hip_library/build

$ make
[ 25%] Linking CXX shared library libhip_sampleLib.so
> nvcc fatal   : "Don't know what to do with '/opt/rocm-5.5.0/lib/libhipblas.so.2.2'"
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hip_sampleLib.dir/build.make:98: libhip_sampleLib.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/hip_sampleLib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

For start, I made sure that my snippet can be compiled in the classical manner:

```bash
hipcc -o hipblas_sgemm.run hipblas_sgemm.cpp -I/opt/rocm/hipblas/include/ -L/opt/rocm/hipblas/lib -lhipblas
```

Then, I proceed to generate the `compile_commands.json` from CMake. However nothing suspicious jumped from sight. Thus it seems to me that the `nvcc` compiler is simply not able to deal with `libhipblas.so` because to the suffix *so.2.2*. (I find this very odd.)

Therefore my questions are:

- Could this be a weakness of nvcc compiler?

If so, do anyone can suggest a work around with CMake?

Comment: You cannot set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER/LINKER` after `project` has been called.